# Stopping and starting .net windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I've a .Net windows service which is on App server 1.
From this service, I need to programmatically start and stop another .Net windows service sitting on App server 2.
How do I achieve this ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

This is an outline of what you will need to do.

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController();
sc.ServiceName = "service name";
sc.MachineName = ".";// for local.  use windows machine name here for a remote service
sc.Start();
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3, 0); // 3 sec
sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running, ts);
if (sc.Status == System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    Console.WriteLine("started");
else
    Console.WriteLine("failed to start");
```

See [MSDN ServiceController information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)

Comment: I added the link that Sam Saffron had in his answer and suggest that @steveChapman should check this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class

Comment: thanks for ur answer...can i also remotely control a windows service using this class?